# Determine if a list of words is in a sentence?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, nlp, nltk

Is there a way (Pattern or Python or NLTK, etc) to detect of a sentence has a list of words in it.

i.e.

`The cat ran into the hat, box, and house.` |  `The list would be hat, box, and house`

This could be string processed but we may have more generic lists:

i.e.

`The cat likes to run outside, run inside, or jump up the stairs.` |

`List=run outside, run inside, or jump up the stairs.`

This could be in the middle of a paragraph or the end of the sentence which further complicates things.

I've been working with Pattern for python for awhile and I'm not seeing a way to go about this and was curious if there is a way with pattern or nltk (natural language tool kit).

Comment: Is your sentence the whole string or do you want to match a sentence within a larger text and return that sentence only?

Comment: Must the words occur in the order given? I.e., are you looking for a subset or a subsequence?

Comment: Are strings that contain those words valid?  Such as "that" having the word "hat" as a substring for example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I am not looking for a list of known words in a sentence. I am interested if it is possible to have a sentence and be able to know if there is a list of words in it.  For example if I had: "I love to walk, run, and bike". I'd like my code to look at this sentence and tell me a list exists and it is: walk, run, and bike.

To further complicate things, I am not guarnated that I will have that exact format. I could have two words in a list, etc.  

My initial thought is to just look at the second to last word, if its and, or then start reading backwards by ","'s as delim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize` ?

```
sent_tokenize("Hello SF Python. This is NLTK.")
["Hello SF Python.", "This is NLTK."]
```

Then you can use that list of sentences in this way:

```
for sentence in my_list:
  # test if this sentence contains the words you want
  # using all() method
```

More info [here](http://www.slideshare.net/japerk/nltk-in-20-minutes)

Comment: This is the closest solution I could come up with. I simply use pattern (or you can use NLTK) to split the sentences up. But before hand I check to see if there is a list by finding out if the next word after the last ',' is and or but.  If it is I back up and read to the previous ','. I set a 3 word max for my lists and this gets me as close as I can to a solution. The problem is that if I have 'the cat jumped over the hat, box, and cup" The first part of the list might be 'over the hat' which is acceptable for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

From what I got from your question, I think you want to search whether all the words in your list is present in a sentence or not.

In general to search for a list elements, in a sentence, you can use `all` function. It returns true, if all the arguments in it are true.

```
listOfWords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'two words']
sentence = "word1 as word2 a fword3 af two words"

if all(word in sentence for word in listOfWords):
    print "All words in sentence"
else:
    print "Missing"
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
"All words in sentence"
```

I think this might serve your purpose. If not, then you can clarify.

Comment: Ok, so Downvoter, can you please comment, rather than sit silently after downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), you will be able to achieve this is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words in the list of words after building a trie with the list of words which takes `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words in the list.

**Algorithm**

- split the sentence into list of words separated by space.
- For each word check if it has a key in the trie. i.e. that word exist in the list

  - if it exits add that word to the result to keep track of how many words from the list appear in the sentence
  - keep track of the words that has a has subtrie that is the current word is a prefix of the longer word in the list of words

    - for each word in this words see by extending it with the current word it can be a key or a subtrie on the list of words
  - if it's a subtrie then we add it to the extend_words list and see if concatenating with the next words we are able to get an exact match.

**Code**

```
import pygtrie
listOfWords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'two words']

trie = pygtrie.StringTrie()
trie._separator = ' '
for word in listOfWords:
  trie[word] = True

print('s', trie._separator)

sentence = "word1 as word2 a fword3 af two words"
sentence_words = sentence.split()
words_found = {}
extended_words = set()

for possible_word in sentence_words:
  has_possible_word = trie.has_node(possible_word)

  if has_possible_word & trie.HAS_VALUE:
    words_found[possible_word] = True

  deep_clone = set(extended_words)
  for extended_word in deep_clone:
    extended_words.remove(extended_word)

    possible_extended_word = extended_word + trie._separator + possible_word
    print(possible_extended_word)
    has_possible_extended_word = trie.has_node(possible_extended_word)

    if has_possible_extended_word & trie.HAS_VALUE:
      words_found[possible_extended_word] = True

    if has_possible_extended_word & trie.HAS_SUBTRIE:
      extended_words.update(possible_extended_word)


  if has_possible_word & trie.HAS_SUBTRIE:
    extended_words.update([possible_word])

print(words_found)
print(len(words_found) == len(listOfWords))
```

This is useful if your list of words is huge and you do not wish to iterate over it every time or you have a large number of queries that over the same list of words.

[The code is here](https://repl.it/repls/OrnateDisgustingTwintext)

Answer (score 0):

```
all(word in sentence for word in listOfWords)
```